# Conversion of Seconds with NSDateFormatter Returns Null

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a string representing seconds into a string with hours minutes seconds format. Input might look like 305 seconds and I want it to show 5:05. Shouldn't I be able to do this using NSDateFormatter? I have tried several variations on the following, but the output is always null.

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"s"];

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

NSString *seconds = @"305";
NSDate *myDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:seconds];
NSString *twelveHourTime = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"twelve hour time: %@", twelveHourTime);
```

I have looked at many of the other NSDate posts, and a lot of the issues are related to incorrect format. Best I can tell from the NSDate formatting guide a single lower case s is the correct input for seconds. That said, I also tried multiple lower case s and upper case S for input format and still did not get correct results.

I'd appreciate knowing what I'm doing wrong, or if this type of conversion is not meant to be done with NSDateFormatter. Thanks.

Comment: There is no version that accepts *three* digits for s.  s is seconds within a minute so only 0 - 59 makes sense.  You can achieve *milliseconds* within a *day* by using A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSDateComponents` to achieve this:

```
NSString *seconds = @"305";

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.second = [seconds integerValue];

NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

NSLog(@"twelve hour time: %@", [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```